# Solution Performance (DP, hashtable) for Partition Equal Subset Sum

Tags: python, algorithm, hashtable, dynamic-programming

I know there are some related questions have already been asked in stackoverflow. However, this question is more related to the **performance** difference among 3 approaches.

The question is: *Given a non-empty array containing only positive integers, find if the array can be partitioned into two subsets such that the sum of elements in both subsets is equal.* https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-equal-subset-sum/

i.e [1, 5, 11, 5] = True, [1, 5, 9] = False

By solving this problem, I have tried 3 approaches:

- Approach 1: Dynamic Programming. Top to Bottom Recursion + memorisation (Result: **Time Limit Exceeded**):

  ```
  def canPartition(nums):
      total, n = sum(nums), len(nums)
      if total & 1 == 1: return False
      half = total >> 1
      mem = [[0 for _ in range(half)] for _ in range(n)]
      def dp(n, half, mem):
          if half == 0: return True
          if n == -1: return False
          if mem[n - 1][half - 1]: return mem[n - 1][half - 1]
          mem[n - 1][half - 1] = dp(n - 1, half, mem) or dp(n - 1, half - nums[n - 1], mem)
          return mem[n - 1][half - 1]
      return dp(n - 1, half, mem)
  ```
- Approach 2: Dynamic Programming. Bottom up. (Result: **2208 ms** *Accepted*):

  ```
  def canPartition(self, nums):
      total, n = sum(nums), len(nums)
      if total & 1 == 1: return False
      half = total >> 1
      matrix = [[0 for _ in range(half + 1)] for _ in range(n)]
      for i in range(n):
          for j in range(1, half + 1):
              if i == 0: 
                  if j >= nums[i]: matrix[i][j] = nums[i]
                  else: matrix[i][j] = 0
              else:
                  if j >= nums[i]:
                      matrix[i][j] = max(matrix[i - 1][j], nums[i] + matrix[i - 1][j - nums[i]])
                  else: matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j]
              if matrix[i][j] == half: return True
      return False
  ```
- Approach 3: HashTable (Dict). Result (**172 ms** *Accepted*):

  ```
  def canPartition(self, nums):
      total = sum(nums)
      if total & 1 == 0:
          half = total >> 1
          cur = {0}
          for number in nums:
              cur |= { number + x for x in cur} # update the dictionary (hashtable) if key doesn't exist
              if half in cur: return True
      return False
  ```

I really don't understand two things for above 3 approaches regarding time complexity:

- I would expect the **approach 1** and **the approach 2** should have the **same result**. Both is using a table (matrix) to record the calculated state, but why bottom up approach is quicker ?
- I don't know why approach 3 is so much quicker compared to the others. Note: as a glance, approach 3 seems to be 2 to Nth Power approach, but it is using dictionary to discard duplicate value, so the time complexity should be **T(n * half)**.

Comment: cur |= { number + x for x in cur} this is a very python paradigm what is it exactly doing?

Comment: update the dictionary (hashtable) if key doesn't exist.

Comment: 1 and 2. this is  a variation of knapsack problem, the time complexity of 1.  is not nW rather 2^n, using recursion in python is awful I am sure leetcode will accomodate for that, anyuways. for 2. the time complexity is nW, for 3. it needs more work at my end to find the expected time of running.

Comment: is { number + x for x in cur} <- a seperate dictionary and |= -> union? or the whole process is just a simple insert?

Answer (score 2):

My guess about the difference between approach 1 and the others is that due to the recursion, approach 1 needs to generate significantly more stack frames, which cost more in system resources than just allocating the matrix and iterating over a conditional. But if I were you, I would try to use some kind of process and memory analyzer to better determine and confirm what's happening. Approach 1 assigns a matrix dependent on the range but the algorithm actually limits the number of iterations to potentially far less since the next function call jumps to a sum subtracted by the array element, rather than combing all possibilities.

Approach 3 depends solely on the number of input elements and the number of sums that can be generated. In each iteration, it adds the current number in the input to all previously achievable numbers, adding only new ones to that list. Given the list `[50000, 50000, 50000]`, for example, approach 3 would iterate over at most three sums: 50000, 100000, and 150000. But since it depends on the range, approach 2 would iterate at least 75000 * 3 times!

Given the list [50000, 50000, 50000], approaches 1, 2 and 3 generate the following numbers of iterations: 15, 225000, and 6.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, Approach 1) and 3) have the same time complexity, approach 2 is the DP version of the knapsack(0/1), approach 1 is the branch and bound version. You can improve approach one by pruning the tree through any of the knapsack heuristics but the optimization has to be strict e.g. if the existing sum and the sum of remaining elements at level K is < half then skip it. This way approach 1) can have better computational complexity than 3).

Why are approach 1) and 3) having a different running time,

[**To some extent**]

That has more to do with the implementation of dictionaries in python. The dictionaries are natively implemented by the Python interpreter, any operation on them is simply going to be faster than anything that needs to be interpreted first and more often. Also, function calls have higher overhead in python, they are objects. So calling one is not a simple bump up stack and jmp/call operation.

[**To a large extent**]

Another aspect to mull on is the time complexity of the third approach. For approach 3, the only way time complexity can be exponential is if each iteration results in the insertion of as many elements as are there in the dictionary for the current iteration.

```
  cur |= { number + x for x in cur}
```

The above line should double |cur|.

I think that it is possible for a series like,

*s = {k,K<sup>2</sup>,K<sup>3</sup>, ..., k<sup>n</sup>, (>K<sup>n+1</sup>)}*

(where K is a prime> 2)
to give the worst case time of order of 2<sup>n</sup> for Approach 3.Not sure yet what is the average expected time complexity.

Comment: It does not seem likely to me that Python's dictionary implementation is a significant contributing factor here. Is there a way you could show that in a test? (Also, it seems to me that only approach 3 is using a dictionary.)

Comment: Fair enough, in your opinion what is a convincing way to establish that? I will also relook the expected runtime of 3 for a normal distribution it might be much less 2^n.

Comment: No sure if could make a convincing test here for the dictionary implementation as a factor because it seems to me that the three algorithms are different. A convincing test would use a similar algorithm and input, once with the Python dictionary and once with another data structure for the same records.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the branch and bound, I hadn't noticed approach 1 was different than 2. (Amended my answer.)

Comment: (Also the idea that Python's implementation of function calls is a contributing factor doesn't seem likely to me either. I think what contributes is the number of function calls being generated by the algorithm, and the overhead of function calls generally.)

Comment: A convincing test of the dictionary and function thing might also be to test the exact same three algorithms and input with a different programming language.

Comment: yes trying it on C++ would be a better way perhaps. I remember having the same conversation a few years back in an optimization course I was taking, folks using python with recursion on knapsack would have their correct code run forever vs the same bits on java. I do agree the order of that function3 is coming into play as well the construct is pretty neat that's why I keep coming back to this problem. :)